# I cannot see a new hard drive in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive

I just installed a Sata WD 500GB hard drive, shows up in BIOS as secondary master drive, but do not see it after boot.  What gives?

```
tone@homeserver:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/hda1             9.2G  3.3G  5.5G  38% /
tmpfs                 881M     0  881M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  740K  9.3M   8% /dev
tmpfs                 881M     0  881M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/hda2              65G  197M   61G   1% /srv
```

Comment: Have you partioned the drive? Created a filesystem on it? Specified a mount point?

Comment: well no that would make too much sense :)  Cole answered my question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -h` just shows the current mount points and stats.

use `fdisk -l` to make sure the machine is seeing the drive.

Next partition the drive:

```
cfdisk /dev/hdc
```

***cfdisk*** will load, then create your partition:

> 1. New >> Primary >> Size in MB
> 2. Once done select Write
> 3. Select Quit

Next format the disk

```
 mkfs.ext3 /dev/hdc1
```

and lastly mount the drive:

```
mkdir /new-disk
mount -t ext3 /dev/hdc1 /new-disk
```

To check to make sure the drive is mounted:

```
ls -lsa /new-disk
```

Comment: What's the command to format a swap partition? mkfs.swap /dev/sda3?

Comment: You don't have to format swap.  Just set the partition type to 82 (Linux Swap).  Then to start using it without rebooting run swapon /dev/sda3

Answer (score 2):

`df` lists all the current mount points and stats.  As root or using sudo and running `fdisk -l` will list all the block devices and partitions that it finds.  From there you'll need to partition and format your new drive and then determine where you want to mount those partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I think df only shows mounted filesystems. Check to see if a /dev/sda is present. If so try mounting it. You could also run parted and then run a print command to see if the drive shows up there as well.

Answer (score 0):

ls /dev | grep hd 
you will see there for example hda hda1 hda2 hda3 hdb hdb1 hdb2
hda and hdb - are hard drives. you need to make partitions using fdisk hdb (for example) and then mount it manualy or define it in /etc/fstab